# How to write jQuery Script more shortly?

Tags: jquery

I'm not a script author. 
But I would like to write more better script.

When Use repeated code, How can I write?

```js
$( ".lecture-0" ).click(function() {
 $( ".lecture-0-video" ).css("display", "block");
});
$( ".lecture-1" ).click(function() {
 $( ".lecture-1-video" ).css("display", "block");
});
$( ".lecture-2" ).click(function() {
 $( ".lecture-2-video" ).css("display", "block");
});

...

$( ".lecture-49" ).click(function() {
 $( ".lecture-49-video" ).css("display", "block");
});
$( ".lecture-50" ).click(function() {
 $( ".lecture-50-video" ).css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: Hello Jaeil!,are you there?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only one class on the element `.lecture-0`, `.lecture-1` etc, You can use wildcard selector like `[class^="lecture-"]` this will return all the elements with the class starting with `lecture-`

`$('[class^="lecture-"]:not([class$="-video"])')` - This selector will return all the class starts with `lecture-` and does not end with `-video`

```
$('[class^="lecture-"]:not([class$="-video"])').click(function() {
    $( ".lecture-" + $(this).attr('class').split("-")[1] + "-video" ).css("display", "block");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind multiple onclick for different class in one function separated by comma

```
$( ".lecture-0,.lecture-1,.lecture-2,.lecture-3" ).click(function(e) {
    var video_class='.'+$(this).attr('class')+'-video';
        $( video_class ).css("display", "block");

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things here that can make writing jQuery a little better:

First, let's look at the `on('click')` instead of `click()`. We want to use the `on('click')` event to also watch for any new dom elements that were added to the page, allowing for events to fire correctly and seamlessly. https://api.jquery.com/on/

Second.. and @2930661/eddie beat me to the second part :) his answer is valid and very nice!